# Connect a sensor to MS azure

Tags: azure, embedded, cloud, iot, sensors

l'am working on RAEM1 sensor , and i want to send his telemetry to MS azure,the problem is i cant develop into that sensor to inject my IOT HUB connexion string to establish the communication and i can't add for exemple a Raspberry pie or any gateway to retreive data from sensor , i need a direct link with MS azure ,this sensor support :

**- WIFI , Ethernet connexion.**

is there any solution that can solve my problem ,or it's impossible to do it without adding an edge gateway ?

Comment: If it can perform http requests than you could write an azure function and send data to it. From there you can route it to any desired azure service. But I suppose that means modifying the code/firmware of that sensor. If that is not an option then how does it communicate?

Comment: Ok, but *he problem is i cant develop into that sensor to inject my IOT HUB connexion string to establish the communication* what is the exact problem?

Comment: the problem is i need to pass throught IOT hub , and i i can't modify they firmware of that sensor , and in the same time i can't add any bridge between this sensor and IOT hub

Comment: You could have the azure function forward the data to the IoT Hub. The function acts as the device. See https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/azure-iot-hub-device-simulation-with-net-c-4c614194f924